# How to create a pandas function that tests if two string exist in multiple panda columns

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I'm trying to write a function that scans through a set of columns and tests if two conditions exist across two different column rows. I'll then use this function and apply it my dataframe.

```py
pattern_one = 'Test1|Exam12'

df = pd.DataFrame({'Project Code':['32132','212132'],'Task Name':['Test 1','Test13']})

def data_filter(project_code, task_name):
    
    if (project_code.str.contains('32132').any() & 
    task_name.str.contains(pattern_one, regex=True).any()):

    output = '45%'
    return(output)
    
    elif:

    output = '0%'
    return(output)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

| Project Code | Task Name |
| --- | --- |
| 32132 | Test1 |
| 212132 | Test13 |

Comment: Should `Test13` match `Test1|Exam12`?

Comment: The question needs to be clarified. can you provide desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a function: use `np.where` with the conditions and if-true and if-false values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"Project Code": ["32132", "212132"],
                   "Task Name" : ["Test1", "Test13"]
                   })

df['out'] = np.where((df["Project Code"].str.contains('32132')) &
                     (df["Task Name"].str.contains('Test1|Exam12')), "45%", "0%")

print(df)
```

gives:

```
  Project Code Task Name  out
0        32132     Test1  45%
1       212132    Test13   0%
```